# I'm trying to iterate, but I'm not getting the expected output in Python

Tags: python, loops, variables, while-loop

I'm writing a code that's supposed to output 2 numbers over and over again until one of them reaches 2. I can't find the mistake, I even used a visualization tool and even though the variables have the expected value, the output comes out wrong. Here's my code:

```
I = 0
J = 1
count = 0
while I <= 2:
    print('I={:.0f} J={:.0f}'.format(I, J))
    J += 1
    count += 1
    if count == 3:
        I += 0.2
        J = 1 + I
        count = 0
```

And here's the expected output:

```
I=0 J=1
I=0 J=2
I=0 J=3
I=0.2 J=1.2
I=0.2 J=2.2
I=0.2 J=3.2
.....
I=2 J=3
I=2 J=4
I=2 J=5
```

Again, when I run it through the vizualizer, I can see that in each step the values assigned to my variables are correct, but the problem is when it prints.

Answer (score 1):

You are truncating the values of `I` and `J` to *zero* decimal places instead of the desired *one*.

```
print('I={:.1f} J={:.1f}'.format(I, J))
```

This, however, shows *all* values to 1 decimal place, even if that digit is a 0. If you really want a mix of integers and floating-point values, you'll have to test the value of `I` and `J` before each `print` and decide how to display them. Something like

```
di = 0 if int(I) == I else 1
dj = 0 if int(J) == J else 1

print(f'I={I:.{di}f} J={J:.{dj}f}')
```

(I'm using an f-string instead of a call to `format` because, honestly, I don't remember how to do inject variables into a format string.)